# Apt for Java subproject

Tags: java, android, plugins

I am developing an Android project. I have a plain java subproject. I would like to activate the apt process for this java subproject. My gradle file:

```
project(':subproject') {
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

dependencies {
    compile files('../app/libs/sqliteannotations-api-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    apt files('../app/libs_annotations/sqliteannotations-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}

}
```

but I get this error:

```
The android or android-library plugin must be applied to the project
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` if you are working on an app.

Add `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` if you are working on a library.